# How do I remove all the extra fields that DOJO datastore adds to my fetched items?

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo, datastore

When fetching an item from a DOJO datastore, DOJO adds a great deal of extra fields to it. It also changes the way the data is structure.

I know I could manually rebuild ever item to its initial form (this would require me to make updates to both JS code everytime i change my REST object), but there certainly has to be a better way.

Perhaps a store.detach( item ) or something of the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dojo.data` API is being phased out, partly because of the extra fields.  You could consider using the new `dojo.store` API.  The store api does not add the extra fields.

I have written a function that does what you are looking to do. It follows.  One thing to note, my function converts child objects to the `{ _reference: 'id' }` notation.  You may want different behavior.

```
Util._detachItem = function(item) {
    var fnIncludeProperty = function(key) {
        return key !== '_0'
            && key !== '_RI'
            && key !== '_RRM'
            && key !== '_S'
            && key !== '__type'
    };

    var store = item._S;

    var fnCreateItemReference = function(itm) {
        if (store.isItem(itm)) {
            return { _reference: itm.id[0] };
        }
        return itm;
    };

    var fnProcessItem = function(itm) {
        var newItm = {};
        for(var k in itm) {
            if(fnIncludeProperty(k)) {
                if (dojo.isArray(itm[k])) {
                    // TODO this could be a problem with arrays with a single item
                    if (itm[k].length == 1) { 
                        newItm[k] = fnCreateItemReference(itm[k][0]);
                    } else {
                        var valArr = [];
                        dojo.forEach(itm[k], function(arrItm) {
                            valArr.push(fnCreateItemReference(arrItm));
                        });
                        newItm[k] = valArr;
                    }
                } else {
                    newItm[k] = fnCreateItemReference(itm[k]);
                }
            }
        }
        return newItm;
    };

    return fnProcessItem(item);
};
```

NOTE: this function is modified from what I originally wrote and I did not test the above code.

Comment: Do these new data.store stores bind to datagrids?

Comment: The dojox.Grid still uses the old Data API.  However, you might be able to give the grid an items array that you manually retrieve from the store.  SitePen has another datagrid option that works with stores at https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid